# Rubidium as hydrogen-like - optical pumping

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

Rubidium is an alkali metal with only a single valence electron.

I read in a lot of optical pumping papers that this enables us to approximate it as hydrogen-like.

I am interested in the significance of this approximation. What does it allow us to do and why do we do it? How does it help us in our explanation of the theory of optical pumping?

Thanks

edit: it allows us to ignore the inner electrons, but my question is on the significance of this...